# How to save Windows 8 update files

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update

Currently I am downloading Windows updates and it is using 2Gb internet. Is there way if I can save it and use it to my other computers? I don't really want to download 10 times.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can download the updates by hand but not through Windows Update.  All updates are posted on the Microsoft website individually.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to download te files several times, use the tool [WSUS Offline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/docs/) to downlaod the updates.

Run the tool and select Which Windows Updates you want to download.

[image]

And click on `Start`. When the Updaets are downloaded, copy the downloaded files to all other PCs, run `UpdateInstaller.exe`

[image]

and click `Start` again to install them.